# Optimise MySql query using temporary and filesort

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this query (shown below) which **currently uses temporary and filesort** in order to generate a grouped by set of  ordered results. I would like to get rid of their usage if possible. I have looked into the underlying indexes used in this query and I just can't see what is missing.

```
SELECT 
  b.institutionid AS b__institutionid,
  b.name AS b__name,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT f2.facebook_id) AS f2__0 
FROM education_institutions b 
LEFT JOIN facebook_education_matches f ON b.institutionid = f.institutionid 
LEFT JOIN facebook_education f2 ON f.school_uid = f2.school_uid 
WHERE 
  (
  b.approved = '1' 
  AND f2.facebook_id IN ( [lots of facebook ids here ])
  ) 
GROUP BY b__institutionid 
ORDER BY f2__0 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Here is the output for `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` :

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                  | key            | key_len | ref                              | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | index  | PRIMARY,institutionId          | institutionId  | 4       | NULL                             |  308 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f2    | ref    | facebook_id_idx,school_uid_idx | school_uid_idx | 9       | f.school_uid                     |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY        | 4       | f.institutionId                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The `CREATE TABLE` statements for each table are shown below so you know the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE facebook_education (
  education_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  school_uid bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  school_type varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  year smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  facebook_id bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  degree varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (education_id),
  KEY facebook_id_idx (facebook_id),
  KEY school_uid_idx (school_uid),
  CONSTRAINT facebook_education_facebook_id_facebook_user_facebook_id FOREIGN KEY (facebook_id) REFERENCES facebook_user (facebook_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=484 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE facebook_education_matches (
  school_uid bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  institutionId int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (school_uid),
  KEY institutionId (institutionId),
  CONSTRAINT fk_facebook_education FOREIGN KEY (school_uid) REFERENCES facebook_education (school_uid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_education_institutions FOREIGN KEY (institutionId) REFERENCES education_institutions (institutionId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE education_institutions (
  institutionId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  type enum('School','Degree') DEFAULT NULL,
  approved tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  deleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  normalisedName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (institutionId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101327 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filesort probably happens because you have no suitable index for the ORDER BY

It's mentioned in the MySQL ["ORDER BY Optimization"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html) docs.

What you can do is load a temp table, select from that afterwards. When you load the temp table, use `ORDER BY NULL`. When you select from the temp table, use `ORDER BY .. LIMIT`

The issue is that group by adds an implicit `order by <group by clause> ASC` unless you disable that behavior by adding a `order by null`.
It's one of those MySQL specific gotcha's.

Comment: It's when I remove the GROUP BY clause though that the 'using filesort' disappears!

Comment: @GordyD: that's why I gave this answer :-)

Comment: Changing the ORDER BY clause to something with an index makes no difference to it using filesort though. It's only when I remove the GROUP BY entirely that no filesort is used. I do not udnerstand at all why your answer relates to this.

Comment: GROUP BY forces a sort, assumes the ORDER BY will be the same (b__institutionid). ORDER BY NULL tells the optimiser to not do this. It is explained in my link

Comment: Ok fair enough, I understand now, thank you for clarifying. Unfortunately though I think creating a temp table is not a viable solution. This query is generated by Doctrine ORM from a DQL query and so I was hoping I could get rid of this issue by adding the required indices. Is there another way to avoid filesort when ordering by the COUNT field I am using.

Comment: @GordyD: I'm not sure in this case. I find MySQL a bit stupid in these matters

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible optimizations,

1. b.approved = '1' - You definitely need an index on approved column for quick filtering.
2. f2.facebook_id IN ( [lots of facebook ids here ]) ) - Store the facebook ids in a temp table,. Then create an index on the temp table and then join with the temp table instead of using IN clause.

Comment: `1.b.approved = '1' - You definitely need an index on approved column for quick filtering.` that will not work, because approved is a boolean field and has a low cardinality, MySQL will simply refuse to use an index.